# How to typecast object data type in custom data type of fields in jooq/java

Tags: java, jooq

I am able to fetch the data from database but while inserting the same data I am getting error related to bad grammar exception which is happening because of data type mismatch.
Let me explain it clearly, There is employee table which has a field of Address type, like this

```
crate table employee{
name varchar,
address Address[];
}
create type Address{
name,
pincode,
.....
}
```

So while fetching the data from db I am getting address type is Object so able to fetch the data but while inserting the data using jooq I am getting the error because it is object type if it is address type then I am able to insert the data
Is there any way in jooq so i can typecast it in Address type in java code.

Comment: Can you please show the exact jOOQ code that you wrote?

Comment: Is Address[] a genuine field column type allowed by the database , it appears more like java syntax. Address may as be a comma separated list as varchar than any object. I believe in an attempt to handle Address[] as the type the database converted the unknown type to Object type, so lookup the DB documentation how to retrieve Object type of the database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're not using code generation? [But you should](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/)! *Especially* when you use user defined types, jOOQ is really of great help. Here's how you can easily insert data to your tables:

```java
AddressRecord[] addresses = {
    new AddressRecord(name1, pincode1, ...),
    new AddressRecord(name2, pincode2, ...)
};

ctx.insertInto(EMPLOYEE)
   .columns(EMPLOYEE.NAME, EMPLOYEE.ADDRESS)
   .values(empname, addresses) // All type safe!
   .execute();
```

No magic. All required type casts will be generated by jOOQ to make sure you can properly insert an array of user defined types. I.e. `cast(? as my_schema.address[])`.

Note, there used to be some bugs in the distant past related to the schema qualification of the UDT type, but those should be resolved in recent releases